# C# Linq-to-SQL Error on submitChanges()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nullreferenceexception, submitchanges

I have a silly problem with Linq to SQl. I only work with C# for 3 weeks but I thought I understand it.

So, now I´m testing my classes (Entites and Manage classes for them) but I get in the initialization of the testclasses an `NullReferenceException`. I read that there are problems with partial classes in Linq but I have only normal classes. Also I have a lot of classes implementet almost the same but only in 2 (of 40) classes appears the exception. Here is a part of the test initialization:

```
     AnimalLine aL = new AnimalLine { ShortName = "Bl6", FullName = "C57Bl6N", Background = "C57Bl6N", SecureEntity = se, Phenotype = "Coat Color = Black", Species = sp };
   ...
     dataContext.GetTable<TumorModel>().InsertOnSubmit(tm);
     AnimalLineInTumorModel aLiTm = new AnimalLineInTumorModel { AnimalLineRole = alr, OntogeneticStage = os, AnimalLine = aL, TumorModel = tm };

    aL.AnimalLinesInTumorModels.Add(aLiTm); // <- if i outcomment this two rows, i have no exception
     alr.AnimalLineInTumorModels.Add(aLiTm); // <- 

     os.AnimalLineInTumorModel.Add(aLiTm);
     tm.AnimalLinesInTumorModels.Add(aLiTm);
     dataContext.GetTable<AnimalLineInTumorModel>().InsertOnSubmit(aLiTm);
 ...
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Here you will find one of the Entities:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using Tumormodelle.BusinessTierObjects.TumorModels;

namespace Tumormodelle.BusinessTierObjects.Animals
{
    [Table(Name = "AnimalLineRole")]
    public class AnimalLineRole : EntityInterface
    {
        // PrimaryKey
        [Column(Name = "AnimalLineRole_ID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int AnimalLineRoleId { get; set; }

        //  normal Column
        [Column(Name = "AnimalLineRole_Name", CanBeNull = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // ForeignKey to AnimalLineInTumorModel (1:M)
        private EntitySet<AnimalLineInTumorModel> _AnimalLineInTumorModels = new EntitySet<AnimalLineInTumorModel>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_AnimalLineInTumorModel_AnimalLineRole", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_AnimalLineInTumorModels", ThisKey = "AnimalLineRoleId", OtherKey = "AnimalLineRoleId")]
        public ICollection<AnimalLineInTumorModel> AnimalLineInTumorModels
        {
            get { return _AnimalLineInTumorModels; }
            set { _AnimalLineInTumorModels.Assign(value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the other side:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using Tumormodelle.BusinessTierObjects.Animals;

namespace Tumormodelle.BusinessTierObjects.TumorModels
{
    [Table(Name = "AnimalLineInTumorModel")]
    public class AnimalLineInTumorModel : EntityInterface
    {
        // PrimaryKey
        [Column(Name = "AnimalLineInTumorModel_ID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int AnimalLineInTumorModelId { get; set; }

        // ForeignKey to AnimalLineRole (M:1)
        [Column(Name = "AnimalLineInTumorModel_FK_Role", CanBeNull=false)]
        private int? AnimalLineRoleId;
        private EntityRef<AnimalLineRole> _AnimalLineRole = new EntityRef<AnimalLineRole>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_AnimalLineInTumorModel_AnimalLineRole", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_AnimalLineRole", ThisKey = "AnimalLineRoleId", OtherKey = "AnimalLineRoleId")]
        public AnimalLineRole AnimalLineRole
        {
            get { return _AnimalLineRole.Entity; }
            set { _AnimalLineRole.Entity = value; }
        }

        // ForeignKey to AnimalLine (M:1)
        [Column(Name = "AnimalLineInTumorModel_FK_AnimalLine", CanBeNull = false)]
        private int? AnimalLineId;
        private EntityRef<AnimalLine> _AnimalLine = new EntityRef<AnimalLine>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_AnimalLineInTumorModel_AnimalLine", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_AnimalLine", ThisKey = "AnimalLineId", OtherKey = "AnimalLineId")]
        public AnimalLine AnimalLine
        {
            get { return _AnimalLine.Entity; }
            set { _AnimalLine.Entity = value; }
        }

        // ForeignKey to OntogeneticStage (M:1)
        [Column(Name = "AnimalLineInTumorModel_FK_OntogeneticStage", CanBeNull = false)]
        private int? OntogeneticStageId;
        private EntityRef<OntogeneticStage> _OntogeneticStage = new EntityRef<OntogeneticStage>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_AnimalLineInTumorModel_OntogeneticStage", IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_OntogeneticStage", ThisKey = "OntogeneticStageId", OtherKey = "OntogeneticStageId")]
        public OntogeneticStage OntogeneticStage
        {
            get { return _OntogeneticStage.Entity; }
            set { _OntogeneticStage.Entity = value; }
        }

       ...
    }
}
```

Here another entity without any problems. It is very similar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using Tumormodelle.BusinessTierObjects.TumorModels;

namespace Tumormodelle.BusinessTierObjects.Animals
{
    [Table(Name="OntogeneticStage")]
    public class OntogeneticStage : EntityInterface
    {
        // Primärschlüssel
        [Column(Name = "OntogeneticStage_ID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int OntogeneticStageId { get; set; }

        // Normale Tabelleneinträge
        [Column(Name = "OntogeneticStage_Name", CanBeNull = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Fremdschlüssel zu AnimalLineInTumorModel (1:M)
        private EntitySet<AnimalLineInTumorModel> _AnimalLineInTumorModel = new EntitySet<AnimalLineInTumorModel>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_AnimalLineInTumorModel_OntogeneticStage", Storage = "_AnimalLineInTumorModel", OtherKey = "OntogeneticStageId", ThisKey = "OntogeneticStageId")]
        public ICollection<AnimalLineInTumorModel> AnimalLineInTumorModel
        {
            get { return _AnimalLineInTumorModel; }
            set { _AnimalLineInTumorModel.Assign(value); }
        }
    }
}
```

They all will look almost the same. And here is the SQL Code to generate the table:

```
dataContext.ExecuteCommand("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AnimalLineRole] 
([AnimalLineRole_ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) ,
[AnimalLineRole_AutoDate] DATETIME CONSTRAINT 
[DF_AnimalLineRole_AnimalLineRole_AutoDate] DEFAULT (getdate()) , 
[AnimalLineRole_Timestamp] ROWVERSION ,
[AnimalLineRole_Comments] NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
[AnimalLineRole_Name] NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AnimalLineRole] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AnimalLineRole_ID] ASC));");
```

I'm totally knocked out by this problem. The debugger can´t help me. `al != null`, `alr != null` and `aLiTm != null`. Where could the `NullReferenceException` come from?

Oh, by the way. The interface `EntityInterface` is empty and just to name some unspecific entities in other methodes. There is no code in it.

Thanks for recognition.

Comment: Linq to SQL is not recommended for new projects. For all intents and purposes it has been deprecated for Linq to EntityFramework

Comment: I can see you have other relationships. Since the `AnimalLine` is not posted here, please check if any of its relationship is **required**. If so, then you should provide the related entity because the related entity cannot be null

Comment: @noobob: They are only to show, that they have no problems and look similar to the classe with the problem. For Example i edited another entity who run.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a new `AnimalLine` instance `aL` but you do not have a `AnimalLinesInTumorModels` collection (Hence the `NullReferenceException`).

You need to initialize the collection, for instace:

```
aL.AnimalLinesInTumorModels = new AnimalLinesInTumorModels();
```

You can also assign this in the `aL` object initializer.

Comment: If id do so vs said: "there was no instance of the abstract class or interface to be created".
Also i don´t make this in any other class (entity) and they all will run.

Comment: Also i checked it in the debugger. The ICollections are definetly != null.